Locust : How to record time for sequential calls
How can I get the time needs for making the call to both endpoints : resource1 and resource2
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, between

class ChainBehavior(TaskSet):
    @task
    def chain_calls(self):
        with self.client.get("/api/v1/resource1", catch_response=True) as response:
            if response.status_code == 200:
                try:
                    resource_id = response.json().get("data")[0].get("id")
                except (IndexError, AttributeError, TypeError):
                    response.failure("Failed to parse resource id")
                    return

                with self.client.get(
                    f"/api/v1/resource2/{resource_id}",
                    name="Call Resource2",
                    catch_response=True,
                ) as response:
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        response.success()
                    else:
                        response.failure("Failed to get resource2")
            else:
                response.failure("Failed to get resource1")

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [ChainBehavior]
    wait_time = between(1, 5)


Locust is providing details about the time taken by both endpoints separately.

according to the docs you could add logging everywhere. So you could log the time  into the logs if that helps
